# OGRE - Create particle system

Tags: customization, textures, ogre, particle-system

Im sorry in advance if this is a stupid question but I just cant seem to find the answer.

I am working on a project in Ogre and what I need is to create a Particle System but instead of using the examples provided by OgreOde, I want one of my own. The difference is I want to create a Praticle System with just one particle and apply a texture to that particle with an image that I already have on my laptop.

Is there a tutorial/example/someone that can help me on this one??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**In general**

The "Particle Script" section in the Ogre manual would be a good place to start: http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/manual/manual_34.html#Particle-Scripts

Another source of inspiration is the particles section in our wiki: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Particles

**Regarding your concrete problem**

You just need a very basic particle script with:

1. quota set to '1' since you only always want one particle
2. a simple material script referring your image/texture
3. an emitter that will spawn the particle, with some settings regarding how long that particle should live and the delay when a new one should be spawned

***However:*** I cannot really image a use case for a single particle, since all you will get is just a single billboard, so why not use a billboard in the first place?